# Slider value change run method within the .m file if x < y

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Sorry if the title was vague. I have this section of code which determines if the slider has been changed.

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.2f", slider.value];
    sliderValue.text = newText;
    if(slider.value <= 0.4){

    }
}
```

I have a method (action) below named: `- (IBAction)fridayEvent:(id)sender {` which gets a url, gets a JSON string and adds pins to a map. I need to be able to call this action when slider value x < y. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you try [self fridayEvent:nil] or if you want to send specific sender using [self fridayEvent:yourSpecificSender] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem. Just do:

```
if( slider.value <= 0.4 ) {
    [self fridayEvent: self];
}
```

or, if your fridayEvent: action needs to query the slider too you can pass it the slider as:

```
[self fridayEvent: slider];
```

Comment: So, where we have `[self` what is self referring to (for my own learning ^^)?

Comment: self is the object that the current method belongs to. Same thing as "this" in C++.